# Setting IIS to protect admin folder

Tags: .net, active-directory, admin

I am using windows authentication with my .NET application, is it possible to set up IIS, so only users who are in the admin group can access the admin folder, and others will get an error?

where do it do it? in code? or is there a setting in IIS?

Answer (score -1):

**Configure Web application for Windows authentication**

To configure your Web application for Windows authentication, follow these steps:

- Click Start, point to Programs, point to Administrative tools, and then click Internet Information Services.
- The Internet Information Services **MMC** appears. Expand Computer, and then expand a Web site that uses Windows authentication.
- Click your Web site application.
- On the Action menu, click Properties.
- In Properties, click the Directory Security tab.
- Under Anonymous access and authentication control, click Edit.
- In Authentication Methods, click to select Integrated Windows authentication. Click to clear all other check boxes.
- Click OK.
- In Properties, click OK. Your Web application is now configured to accept valid user accounts.

Then inside your web.config, Enable windows authentication.

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
```

Also you need to enable **RoleManage** inside your web.config
**AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider** is defined in machine.config so you just need to set.

```
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider"></roleManager>
```

Then you can allow and deny specific users or users' groups (roles)

```
<configuration>
<!-- empty means files at root path -->
 <location path="">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <!--Allowing any user of Administrators group,
        you can provide more separating by comma-->
      <allow roles="domainname\Administrators" />
      <deny users="*" />    <!-- * mean any user-->
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
 </location>
</configuration>

<configuration>
<!-- means all files inside AdminFolder -->
 <location path="AdminFolder">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <!--Allowing any user of Administrators group,
        you can provide more separating by comma-->
      <allow roles="domainname\Administrators" />
      <deny users="*" />    <!-- * mean any user-->
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
 </location>
</configuration>
```

I have tested it and it worked. Keep more reading [How To: Use Windows Authentication in ASP.NET 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647405.aspx)

Good Luck!